# Java httpServletRequest Into Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page that calls a JavaScript function to dynamically create content like this:

```
<input type="text" name="loadLocation1"  id="loadLocation1"  class="loadLocation />
<input type="text" name="loadMagnitude1" id="loadMagnitude1" class="loadMagnitude / >

<input type="text" name="loadLocation2"  id="loadLocation2"  class="loadLocation />
<input type="text" name="loadMagnitude2" id="loadMagnitude2" class="loadMagnitude / >

and so on
```

My goal is to end up with two separate arraysLists containing:

```
[loadLocation1,  loadLocation2,  etc.]
[loadMagnitude1, loadMagnitude2, etc.]
```

Right now I have a servlet that is separating out the data into two different arrays in a rather stupid way:

```
if(req.getParameter("loadLocation1"  ) != null ) {
                beam.appendForceDistance( Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("loadLocation1"  )));
                beam.appendForce(         Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("loadMagnitude1" )));


if(req.getParameter("loadLocation2"  ) != null ) {
                beam.appendForceDistance( Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("loadLocation2"  )));
                beam.appendForce(         Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("loadMagnitude2" )));

etc.
```

Which isn't expandable at all. I've looked at the HttpServletRequest documentation, without much luck. I was able to iterate over a map and get the strings of keys and values to print out which wasn't much help since I couldn't separate results by class name.

Also, the getAttribute() looked promising, but when I called it on a request:

```
req.getAttribute("loadLocation")
```

it returns null.

Is there any way to separate the two types of data based on class into two different arrays while maintaining the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible.
When the form is submitted only the form elements with the "name" attribute will be submitted. 
The order will remain exactly the same so that part is solved.

What I would suggest is to create the Object with javascript and post that with ajax.

```
// One Load object
function Load(args) {
    this.kind = args.kind || null; // Location or Magnitude
    this.value = args.value || null;
    this.clazz = args.clazz || null;
}


    var arr = new Array();
      var loads = document.getElementsByName('load');
   for (var i=0; i< loads.length; i++) {

    arr[i] = new Load({
                kind: loads[i].id,
                value: loads[i].value.
                clazz: loads[i].getAttribute('class').
    });
   }
```

Use JQuery to post this:

```
$.postJSON(getHost() + "save/load",arr, function(data) {

        });
```

And your jsp looks like this

```
<input type="text" name="load"   class="loadLocation />
<input type="text" name="load" class="loadMagnitude / >

<input type="text" name="load"  class="loadLocation />
<input type="text" name="load"  class="loadMagnitude / >
```

The code is not tested or perfect but you get the idea I hope.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful just to know what I was doing wasn't possible so I can stop looking down that dead end. 

I'm not familiar with AJAX, but been reading up on it for the past couple of hours it sounds like what you are suggesting will probably work.